# C#/UWP Hide NavigationView after button selection

Tags: c#, uwp, uwp-xaml

Im bumping into an issue currently where clicking on an AppBarButton doesnt minimise the NavView after navigating. Unlike the NavView_SelectionChanged void which minimises NavView automatically after selecting a NavigationViewItem.
Im not sure how to hide the NavView after updating the Content Frame.

Here is the MainPage.xaml.cs

```
public sealed partial class MainPage : Page
    {

        public MainPage()
        {
            this.InitializeComponent();

            string appName = Windows.ApplicationModel.Package.Current.DisplayName;
        }

        private void NavView_SelectionChanged(Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls.NavigationView sender, Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls.NavigationViewSelectionChangedEventArgs args)
        {
            NavigationViewItem item = args.SelectedItem as NavigationViewItem;

            switch (item.Tag.ToString())
            {
                case "OverView_Page":
                    ContentFrame.Navigate(typeof(Content_Pages.Overview_Page));
                    break;
                case "Bills_Page":
                    ContentFrame.Navigate(typeof(Content_Pages.Bills_Page));
                    break;
                case "BillPayer_Page":
                    ContentFrame.Navigate(typeof(Content_Pages.BillPayer_Page));
                    break;
                case "Transfers_Page":
                    ContentFrame.Navigate(typeof(Content_Pages.Transfers_Page));
                    break;
                case "PayDates_Page":
                    ContentFrame.Navigate(typeof(Content_Pages.PayDates_Page));
                    break;               
            }
        }
       private void SettingsButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            ContentFrame.Navigate(typeof(Content_Pages.SettingsPage));
        }
    }
```

And the MainPage.XAML AppBarButtons:

```
<mux:NavigationView.MenuItems>
                <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" UseLayoutRounding="False">
                    <AppBarButton Icon="Setting" Margin="1, 2, 0, 0" Tag="Settings_Page" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Width="56.5" Height="56.5" ClickMode="Press" Click="SettingsButton_Click"/> 
                </StackPanel>
```

All of these are closed off correctly so these are just the relevant bits. Please excuse my lack of knowledge on this, still learning

Comment: Did you try to set the `IsPaneOpen` property to `false` after calling `Navigate`?

Comment: it wouldnt accept it as a valid option unfortunately. Then again, im probably not doing it right

Comment: Not a valid option? Did you try it?

Comment: I did attempt to set IsPaneOpen. I just dont really know what im doing with it

Comment: Try to add this line after `ContentFrame.Navigate` in `SettingsButton_Click`: `NavView.IsPanelOpen = false;`

Comment: I feel like a right idiot. Ive been trying with NavigationView NOT NavView, I completely forgot about NavView -_- Thank you so much for this! It works now!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add this line after the call to `ContentFrame.Navigate` in `SettingsButton_Click`:

```
NavView.IsPanelOpen = false;
```

Comment: Thank you for this. All your help is appreciated

Answer (score 1):

first of all I would recommend you to use the latest version of **NavigationView** in the new **winui** library : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/design/controls-and-patterns/navigationview

**Relevent parts from the docs above**

> NavigationView can be set to different display modes, via the **PaneDisplayMode** property: for your scenario you can toggle between values : **Left** and **LeftCompact**.
>
> whenever user clicks an appbar button its clicked event will be invoked, within that event you can set the **PaneDisplayMode** property to your desired value and that way you can control when the NavigationView hidesor shows or whatever you want it to do basically u can do a lot with this newer version of the control, read the docs link above for more detailed docs. Hope this helps.

Comment: Many thanks for this. Ive gone through and read the documents as best I can understand them. The PaneDisplayMode is already pre-defined in the XAML. Ive over-ridden the deafault and just use "left minimal". As such, i tried to use mm8s suggestion on setting IsPaneOpenProperty. Im just getting nowhere with it as the documentation is very light for what i need.

Comment: Im using this to understand properties and get/sets: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/properties  . Im just not sure how to implement this into the IsPaneOpenProperty or even PaneDisplayMode for that matter

Comment: @Batteredburrito u dnt need to deep dive into getters and setters for this u just need to simply set the property like "MyNavigationView.PaneDisplayMode = ur desired value" u can see how to do that in xaml or even in c# in the docs I provided in my answer

Comment: Thanks for this. I will keep all of this saved as i know it will help later on in my project. I really appreciate your time on this